# Copy random rows from one table to another

Tags: android, sqlite

I have one problem, I need copy random rows from one table to another,can anybody tell me text for query?  I have found some sourte of this code

```
INSERT INTO Table1 FROM Table2 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 3
```

is it correct?

Comment: why you do not check yourself?

Comment: there is no oportunity to chech it now,only in few days, but it's really important,so i think there are peoples here, who is smarter than me,and can say is it correct or not, without checking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably look up what it does yourself and test it.

It will insert into Table1, From Table2 three random rows

This may not be exactly what you want, you haven’t quite said.

To randomize all rows, then you would run the above but remove the LIMIT keyword.